# unable to start Apache and MySql - busy ports

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I am not able to start Apache and MySql using XAMPP. The error I get is that **the 80 and 443 ports are busy.**

I looked over the Internet for solutions and most, like this one: http://www.sitepoint.com/unblock-port-80-on-windows-run-apache/
seem to imply to remove Skype, uninstall Ms Sql Server who might be using those ports, etc. I am not interested however in removing any current program (I have Sql Server and need that one too).

So I am mostly interested if there is a way to make Apache and MySql use a port which is not used by other applications. (Shouldn't, ideally, each new installed program "skim" over the list of all ports and pick randomly one that is not busy, so one wouldn't have to struggle with this?).

Kindly see picture below:
[image]
I pressed the Config button (right-most one, from the last column of buttons) and the "Service settings" window opened. There I played with a few variants, like 8081 instead of 80 for Apache main port, etc. When I tried to start the service again, no results still.

Is this the right way to handle this and what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a try by disabling HTTPS.For this go to your xampp cmd prompt and disable HTTPS(ssl) by selecting 3.

Answer (score 0):

Change apache port and try to start again